# How to create an interactive Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I've been asked to code a Facebook page, and I have no idea where to start. A bit of googling around has lead me FBML (Facebook markup language) but I can't find anything definitive in the help or any good tutorials on how to code a custom facebook page.

Anyone have any great links on how to create a Facebook page? Beyond actually just making the page on Facebook. Things such as embedding video, adding backgrounds, forms, animation and fully featured web page type functionality.

The design we have has all these elements, along with pulling RSS feeds and such.

Any help, or direction would be great!
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use [FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) anymore!

> We are in the process of deprecating FBML. If you are building a new
>   application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using
>   HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

A facebook app/page is a simple html site where you connect to facebook via the Facebook API. In the meantime the facebook documentation has become quite readable. Have a look at:

- [SDK tools](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) (JS and PHP)
- [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (how to know who the user is)
- [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) (the user has to approve that you may gather information)
- [The Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (how to get informations)
- [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) (how to interact on the clientside)

Comment: Ah excellent! No wonder I was struggling, looking at the wrong thing entirely! Thanks